# Did both the Elder Wand AND Lily's protection protect Harry the second time?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, albus-dumbledore, deathly-hallows, lily-potter

In the Forbidden Forest, it was, as Dumbledore explained, Lily's protection -- which was in Harry AS WELL AS Voldemort -- that saved Harry from the Killing Curse. But was it also the fact that Voldemort used the Elder Wand -- whose true master was Harry at the time -- which led it to kill the only foreign thing in Harry; that is to say, the part of Voldemort's soul in Harry?

Answer (score 1):

**It is unclear**

There is no direct evidence in the text either way, but the bulk of the text dealing with wand loyalties may very well be read to support that hypothesis *as a contributing factor*.

However, what saved Harry was primarily the combination of Lily's sacrifice *and* Voldemort's mistakes -- unwittingly binding his life to Harry's (remember the prophecy).

Voldemort's soul-fragment was destroyed, but Voldemort himself lived so Harry lived -- that is, Harry had the choice to live, which he elected to do.

(This was why Dumbledore was so pleased when Voldemort bound Lily's sacrifice to himself. Before that, Harry had to die in order to destroy the soul-piece. But afterward it was no longer certain that he needed to remain dead.)